# regex Scala for replacing all but white space and specified target

Tags: regex, scala

My initial code, but its taking all the numbers irrespective of length. I need to replace only 5 consecutive numbers preceding one hash.

```
val st="ABC  #12345768 213123 Checks juan #54321 asda"
val Replace= "([^\\s|'(#\\[0-9\\]{5})'])".r
val new_value= Replace.replaceAllIn(st, "X")
println(new_value)
```

The expected output:

```
XXX  XXXXXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXX XXXX #54321 XXXX
```

Comment: What is the expected output? Try `val Replace = """#\d{5}(?!\d)\s*""".r` or even `val Replace = """#\d{5}(?:\s+|$)""".r` if there are always whitespaces after the 5 digit numbers.

Comment: the expected output:  XXX   XXXXXXXXX  XXXXXX XXXXXX XXXX #54321 XXXX

Comment: its not working what you suggested

Comment: I know. You need to use a callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
val st = "ABC  #12345768 213123 Checks juan #54321 asda"
val Replace = """(#\d{5})(?!\d)|\S""".r
val new_value= Replace replaceAllIn (st, m => if (m.group(1) == null) "X" else m.group(1) )
println(new_value)
// => XXX  XXXXXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXX XXXX #54321 XXXX
```

See the [Scala demo](https://ideone.com/Sy4LxC).

**Details**

- `(#\d{5})(?!\d)` - matches and captures into Group 1 a hash symbol and 5 digits after it that are not followed with a digit
- `|` - or
- `\S` - just matches a non-whitespace char.

The match is processed inside a callback: `if (m.group(1) == null) "X" else m.group(1)` means that if Group 1 matched, replace with the group value (do not replace the match), else, replace the found char with `X`.

Comment: Note: if you are dealing with whitespace separated fields, `"""(#\d{5})(?!\S)|\S""".r` might be more precise. Also, a mere word boundary after the 5-digit pattern `"""(#\d{5})\b|\S""".r` might also work.

Comment: can you help me in adding below pattern in same : [a-zA-z0-9(]*844?[-.\\s)]?379[-.\\s]?0370

Comment: @user7006069 What do you want to do with that pattern? Keep? Just add it to the capturing group - `val Replace = """(#\d{5}\b|[a-zA-Z0-9(]*844?[-.\s)]?379[-.\s]?0370)|\S""".r`

Comment: Thank you so much , it worked, its just for my project :) :)

Answer (score 1):

This will work, but only if your target is space-Char delimited.

```
val st = "ABC  #12345768 213123 Checks juan #54321 asda"
val new_value = st.split(" ").map{ s =>
  if (s matches "#\\d{5}") s
  else "X" * s.length
}.mkString(" ")
//new_value: String = XXX  XXXXXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXX XXXX #54321 XXXX
```